# Error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of null" when commit Firestore batch

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I got the following error when trying to batch delete a collection:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of null
>
> at Function.fromProto (..\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\timestamp.js:91:47)

The code is plain simple (written in TypeScript):

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
...
var batch: FirebaseFirestore.WriteBatch = admin.firestore().batch();
return generic.application.admin.firestore().collection(name)
    .get()
    .then((docs: FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot) => {
        docs.docs.forEach((doc:any) => {
            batch.delete(doc.ref);
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
        return batch.commit();
    });
```

Happens when the collection is emtpy;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding a counter so i can avoid commit when the collection is empty.

The issue was found firebase admin sdk version 5.13.0 but still present on version 5.13.1. More information can be found [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/312).